# git error on rvm update: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge on rvm get head command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby 2 with rvm, on updating rvm the following error appears

```
From git://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 514dedf..75e457c
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
.gitignore
FORMATTING.md
HACKING.md
README
VERSION
config/db
config/known
config/md5
config/remote
config/sha512
docs/rvm.txt
docs/vm_setup.md
docs/vm_tests.md
help/alias.md
help/benchmark.md
help/cleanup.md
help/current.md
help/disk-usage.md
help/do.md
help/fetch.md
help/info.md
help/migrate.md
help/rake.md
help/remove.md
help/repair.md
help/ruby.md
help/rubygems.md
help/rvmrc.md
help/rvmrc/to.md
help/rvmrc/warning.md
help/snapshot.md
help/tools.md
help/uninstall.md
help/upgrade-notes.txt
help/use.md
help/wrapper.md
hooks/after_cd_bundler
hooks/after_install_codesign
man/man1/rvm.1
man/man1/rvm.1.gz
rubygems-2.0.4.tgz
scripts/aliases
scripts/extras/chruby.sh
scripts/extras/completion.zsh/_rvm
scripts/extras/rails
scripts/fix-permissions
scripts/functions/build
scripts/functions/db
scripts/functions/env
scripts/functions/environment
scripts/functions/gemset
scripts/functions/group
scripts/functions/hooks/jruby
scripts/functions/implode
scripts/functions/init
scripts/functions/install
scripts/functions/installer
scripts/functions/irbrc
scripts/functions/logging
scripts/functions/manage/base
scripts/functions/manage/goruby
scripts/functions/manage/ironruby
scripts/functions/manage/jruby
scripts/functions/manage/macruby
scripts/functions/manage/maglev
scripts/functions/manage/mruby
scripts/functions/manage/opal
scripts/functions/manage/ree
scripts/functions/manage/rubinius
scripts/functions/manage/ruby
scripts/functions/osx-support
scripts/functions/requirements/rvm_pkg
scripts/functions/reset
scripts/functions/rvmrc
scripts/functions/rvmrc_project
scripts/functions/rvmrc_set
scripts/functions/rvmrc_trust
scripts/functions/rvmrc_warning
scripts/functions/support
scripts/functions/utility
scripts/functions/utility_gems
scripts/functions/utility_logging
scripts/functions/utility_package
scripts/functions/utility_system
scripts/hook
scripts/irbrc
scripts/irbrc.rb
scripts/notes
update-remote.sh
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

Installed RVM HEAD version:

rvm 1.6.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

I have tried everything to fix this but nothing helped..please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your rvm is very old and there was a tricky system of updating, you can update with installer - run:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm reload
```

and continue with installing ruby.